# Denied boarding in Amman for flight to USA via Frankfurt

Tags: tickets, lufthansa, syrian-citizens, amman

I have a visitor visa for USA and booked a Lufthansa flight from Amman to Chicago with a transit in Frankfurt. I was denied boarding at Amman and told I have a problem with the embassy.

I went to the embassy and they gave me the USCIS email to contact but couldn't help, then they gave me another email to contact, which was ustraveldocs email. I emailed them and they told me that your visa is still working.

Who should I contact to know the problem?

Is it because i did not have a transit visa ?

Comment: It is not logical, they just denied you for no reason! just like that? did someone come to you and said "I do not want you to board for no reason"?

Comment: If you had some sort of explanation, someone might be able to provide some details or explain what you could do next but if you don't know the reason, then we don't know either.

Comment: They told me that i have a problem with the embassy .. I went to the embassy and they gave me the USCIS email to contact .. I emailed them but they couldnt help me .. I dont know what to do !

Comment: So you answered yourself.. anyway, how do you know they could not help? what was their reply?

Comment: They gave me another email to contact .. Which was ustraveldocs email .. I emailed them and they told me that ur visa is still working .. Who should i contact to know the problem .. Is it possible to get a ticket from another plane ? Will that work ?

Comment: @Amr come on ya zalame, all these information must be in the question so we can help properly..

Comment: Done Nean Der Thal

Comment: The airline told me i have problems worh both germany and usa .. Ive been contacting usa for the past 2 days and no one knew my problem .. Im starting to beleive that it is the airline's fault

Comment: May be they are oversold, and then kick someone off

Comment: Another possible answer is that you are banned by the airline because of misconduct in previous flight

Comment: BTW if you are denied boarding with no acceptable reasons, you can call for compensation or full refund (http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/passenger-rights/air/index_en.htm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the information you have supplied here, you were wrongly denied boarding. Your U.S. visa was sufficient to make the transit:

```
Information as of  23AUG15 / 0855 UTC
National Syria (SY)             /Residence Jordan (JO)
Embarkation Jordan (JO)         /Transit Germany (DE)
Destination USA (US)
ALSO CHECK DESTINATION INFORMATION BELOW

Germany (DE)

TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
Visa required, except for Nationals of Syria holding onward
through Cologne/Bonn (CGN),
Frankfurt (FRA), Munich (MUC), Hamburg (HAM), Dusseldorf (DUS)
or Berlin Tegel (TXL) **AND** meeting one of the following
conditions:
- holding a valid visa issued by Bulgaria, Canada, Croatia,
Cyprus, Ireland (Rep.), Japan, Romania, USA or United
Kingdom;

- WARNING: TWOV is not possible when arriving from a
non-Schengen Member State AND departing to a Schengen Member
```

I think you should make a complaint to Lufthansa (for the poor customer service) and ask them to reinstate your ticket for travel at your convenience.

Stick to the facts, just say what happened, provide a photocopy of the visa and provide a copy of the email from the embassy saying everything is okay. No need for any emotion. I would not discuss compensation at this stage, but you are possibly entitled to it. Better to seek that later.

In future if this happens I would ask to speak with the Lufthansa Station Manager (who is a Lufthansa employee) rather than just accept what the check-in person says. At outstations, the check-in employees are often local contractors who are not familiar with the airline's rules and they are often poorly trained.